# How to set a Rails database to provide both api-rails services and regular views?

Tags: android, html, ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I am developing an Android app that will communicate with a web database working on rails. For that I've decided to use rails-api for passing the data to the application using json. That works totally fine.

However, I have to provide also a way for non-technical human users to feed the data into the database. I was thinking of building the regular views (edit, show, new, delete, whatnot) provided by the scaffolding of rails, but this doesn't seem to be possible.

Is there a way to set up the web database to work with the API AND to also provide views for human users that may modify the database?

Comment: this is definitely possible. have you checked out the RailsCasts on API's? You can have controllers namespaced under Api that handle the JSON API, and separate controllers that are not namespaced (like what the scaffold would generate) to serve the HTTP requests for your normal UI.

Comment: Here's a simple example of what the API controller might look like (this does not use the Rails API gem, but how you implement the API shouldn't impact your other non-API controllers) http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to explain my comments as a formal answer. Your database can serve data for both the API and web interface. You just need to create 2 sets of controllers, one for the API and one for the web UI. Assuming you have a model called Post and you only want to create an index action for your API and web interface, it might look something like this:

**API**

```
# app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb

module Api
  module V1
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :json

      def index
        respond_with Post.all
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Web**

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
```

Your routes should look something like this:

**Routes**

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :posts
  end
end
resources :posts
```

Then you should be able to view the list of posts by creating `app/views/posts/index.html.erb` and visiting domain.com/posts. the API would be accessible at domain.com/api/v1/posts.json

Comment: @dvanverb: I would have never figured this out! Thank you!
So, the json api is working as I desire, I just need the web UI. Can I just copy all the controllers I currently have into the directory path you specified, adding the `respond_to :json` line you added? Will it automatically redirect json request to those controllers? Would I just write the regular controllers and views on the original controllers folder?

Comment: you're going to need to set up separate routes for the API as well. For the web views, you'd just do `resources :posts`, and for the api you would do something like

    namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
      scope :v1 do
        resources :posts
      end
    end

Comment: I already did the changes you specified. With the appropiate controllers, the web UI is working perfectly fine! However, the json api is not working.
I am using RESTclient plug-in for Firefox. If I try connecting using a json header, I get the regular web UI. If I remove the web UI controllers, i get the Rounting Error: uninitialized constant [modelname]Controller. Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: Assuming you used the routes and set up your controllers for the API like I suggested, you'd want to access the API at `/api/v1/posts.json`. Is that what you are trying to do when you get that error?